# Finding dy/dx by implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Find dy/dx by implicit differentiation

x^2-4xy+y^2=4

I know to take the derivatives of both sides, which would be:

d/dx[x^2-4xy+y^2]=0

I'm not sure if I did it right, but I then got:

2x-4*(x*dy/dx)+y+2y*(dy/dx)=0

I don't know where to go from here, or even if the previous step is correct. Please help!

Edit: I have followed the advice given and I ended up with:

(x-2y)/(2x-1)

However this was incorrect. Someone please tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: If you simply expand the parentheses following $-4$ to include $+y$, so that you have $$2x-4\left(x\frac{dy}{dx} +y\right)+ 2y\frac{dy}{dx}=2x-4x\frac{dy}{dx} -4y+ 2y\frac{dy}{dx} $$ then all is good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close! You forgot a coefficient on the $y$ term. You should have
$$
2x-4y-4x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0
$$
Now you can solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ like any other variable.

Comment: I did that and got (2x-4y)/(4x-2) is this correct? I don't think you can reduce that.

Comment: Well, "2" can be factored out of both numerator and denominator so it certainly **can** be reduced.

Comment: (x-2y)/(2x-1) was incorrect. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Maggie To repeat this part of the answer: `You forgot a coefficient on the y term`.

Comment: The $2x-1$ in the denomintor should be a $2x-y$. It looks like you just lost track of the $y$